# My app no longer asks for the users permission to write external storage, why?

Tags: java, android, permissions, share, manifest

I updated my app few days ago and notice that the share function to share a sound no longer works.
I didn't changed anything on the code except I migrated to AndroidX.

Here is the Logcat message:

```
E/EVENTHANDLER: Failed to save file: /storage/emulated/0/appfolder/testsound.mp3 (Permission denied)
```

And here is the Method where it should ask for the users permission:

```
     if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_send){

                        try{

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){


                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(view.getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) view.getContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                                }else {
                                    final String AUTHORITY = view.getContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";

                                    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(view.getContext(), AUTHORITY, file);
                                    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
                                    intent.setType("audio/mp3");
                                    view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share sound via..."));
                                }


                            }
                            else {
                                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                                Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
                                intent.setType("audio/mp3");
                                view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share sound via..."));
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e){

                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to share sound: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
```

Here is the method where the sound is downloaded:

```
               if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_send || item.getItemId() == R.id.action_ringtone){


SoundObject AND add the .mp3 tag to it
                final String fileName = soundObject.getItemName() + ".mp3";

                File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File directory = new File(storage.getAbsolutePath() + "/appfolder/");

                directory.mkdirs();

                final File file = new File(directory, fileName);

                InputStream in = view.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(soundObject.getItemID());

                try{

                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Saving sound " + soundObject.getItemName());

                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1){
                        out.write(buffer, 0 , len);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    out.close();

                } catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to save file: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This is the method where it asks for the storage Acess:

```
public void externalStorageAccess(){
    final File FILES_PATH = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/files");
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(
            Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        if (!FILES_PATH.mkdirs()) {
            Log.w("error", "Could not create " + FILES_PATH);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Of course I have these two line in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Why is it no longer working? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Has the user selected the "Never ask again" option? In that case, the system won't prompt them again and you have to cater for that using shouldshowrequestpermissionrationale()

Comment: @NikosHidalgo No I also cant share a sound eventhoug I reinstalled the app

Comment: If you put breakpoints on the checks what is the path that your app follows in the code above? If you go to the permissions page are they all enabled/disabled?

Comment: `Failed to save file:`. You posted the wrong code. You should post the code where you try to save that file.

Comment: Are you compiling for Android Q (10) ?

Comment: @blackapps Yes I migrated the code to AndroidX

Comment: If you try or compile on Android Q, it can be the reason according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE):  `If this permission is not whitelisted for an app that targets an API level before Build.VERSION_CODES.Q this permission cannot be granted to apps.`

Comment: Under Android Q when your target version is Android Q your app has no access to /storage/emulated/0. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); is not usable any more then.

Comment: @AytekSökmen so what can I do about it?

Comment: Take a different path: getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir() and getExtenalFilesDirs().

Comment: @blackapps can I change the path?

Comment: ???? well read my last comment.

Comment: Oh fortgot the word "how" and "where", sorry

Comment: Can you review [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped#toggle-behavior-change)?

Comment: @AytekSökmen I would be really glad if you could show me what I have to change in my case, I'm not that good at coding.

Comment: @blackapps I added the method where it asks for ExternalStorageAccess in my question above, can you show me how to change the path correctly? I tried it like that: new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/files");  But that doesnt work

Comment: File dir = getExternalFilesDir(null); Then have a look at dir.getAbsolutePath(); And you do not need to request read or write permissions for this app private directory. You have them by default.

Comment: @blackapps Where do I have to put dir.getAbsolutePath()? I am not that good at coding, can you please show me how to change the code in my case? I will give you a green check mark. I would be so glad if you could do that for me real quick, getting many bad reviews atm because the user can't share and I'm too dumb to fix it

Comment: if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(
            Environment.getExternalStorageState()))   Remove that. That was for ExternalStorage directory.

Comment: `Where do I have to put dir.getAbsolutePath()?` Well i advised you to have a look at the value so you know which path it is. Where you log or toast the value is up to you.

Comment: `if (!FILES_PATH.mkdirs()) ` If the directory already exists mkdirs() will return false. Only call mkdir() or mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet.

Comment: `This is the method where it asks for the storage Acess:` You are not asking anything there. Also you do not do anything with the result. Remove that function.

Comment: @blackapps Sadly I'm too new to android studio to understand what you are saying, I just wanted that you respond to my question with the code I just can copy and paste into my code. But thank you anyway!!, I try to find someone who can do that for me.